# How can I set nulls in my pandas dataframe column with a different value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set some null values in my dataframe to a different value: 'Non-étiquettés'

```
page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'].loc[page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'].isnull()] = page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'].loc[page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'].isnull()].apply(lambda x: ['Non-étiquettés'])
```

However, setting the values using this method above results in this warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

After reading the documentation and attempting to adjust my code, I try this...

```
dfc = page_data_fr.copy() 

mask = dfc['Lookup_FR_tag'].loc[page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'].isnull()]

dfc['Lookup_FR_tag'].loc[mask, 'Lookup_FR_tag'] = 'Non-étiquettés'
```

This still generates another error:

> ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
> dfc['Lookup_FR_tag'].loc[page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'].isnull()]

I have also tried doing it this way which is still no good:

```
arrOfNulls = []
counter = 0
for x in dfc['Lookup_FR_tag'].isnull():
   if x == True:
      arrOfNulls.append(counter)
      counter += 1
counter += 1

for x in range(len(arrOfNulls)):
    page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'][arrOfNulls[x]] = ['Non-étiquettés']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if I am close..

Comment: Have you considered using `DataFrame.fillna()` or `Series.fillna()` method?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas-series-fillna

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
 import numpy as np
 
 page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'].replace(np.nan,"Non-étiquettés")
```

Comment: This did not work or change any of my values unfortunately

Comment: you need to replace np.nan by the form your missing values ​​take. For example if your missing values ​​are coded with 0, you must write .replace (0,"Non-étiquettés")

Comment: I did, I tried this 
`>>> page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'] = page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'].replace(np.nan,"Non-étiquettés")
>>> page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'][22]
'Non-étiquettés'`

It works, however it is replacing them with string, I need to replace with an array containing the string, I try this:
`page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag']= page_data_fr['Lookup_FR_tag'].replace(np.nan,['Non-étiquettés'])

TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'float'`